# Chunked responses in libevent2

Tags: c, libevent, transfer-encoding, chunked-encoding

I am trying to do a chunked response (of large files) in libevent this way::

```
evhttp_send_reply_start(request, HTTP_OK, "OK");

int fd = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
size_t fileSize = <get_file_size>;
struct evbuffer *databuff = NULL;
for (off_t offset = 0;offset < fileSize;)
{
    databuff = evbuffer_new();

    size_t bytesLeft = fileSize - offset;
    size_t bytesToRead = bytesLeft > MAX_READ_SIZE ? MAX_READ_SIZE : bytesLeft;

    evbuffer_add_file(databuff, fd, offset, bytesToRead);
    offset += bytesToRead;

    evhttp_send_reply_chunk(request, databuff); // send it
    evbuffer_free(databuff);                    // destroy it
}

evhttp_send_reply_end(request);

fclose(fptr);
```

---

Problem is with this I have a feeling the add_file is asynchronous so the 3rd or so `evhttp_send_reply_chunk` gives me an error (or something similar):

> [warn] evhttp_send_chain Closed(45): Bad file descriptor

I set `MAX_READ_SIZE` to be `8` to actually test out chunked transfer encoding.

I noticed there was a `evhttp_request_set_chunked_cb  (struct evhttp_request  *, void(*cb)(struct evhttp_request  *, void *))`  method I could use but could not find any examples on how to use.

For instance, how could I pass an argument to the callback?  The argument seems to be the same argument that was passed to the request handler which is not what I want, because I want to create an object that holds the file descriptor and the file offset I am sending out.

Appreciate all help.

Thanks in advance
Sri

Answer (score 0):

The [libevent v2 documentation](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-2.0.1/buffer_8h.html#061d40118931d4aa2292ccb8b2f432d1) doesn't say that it's async, but it does say that it closes the file descriptor which your code doesn't account for.

I believe you need to move `int fd = open("filename", O_RDONLY);` inside your loop.

you can also test the chunk handling outside of your file code by just building a string buffer from scratch.

aside from that, (and the last line which should be `fclose(fp);` your example looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Nice Nice mate.  Thanks for that.  I just realised that the only reason I wanted to chunked transfers were to avoid buffer reads.  But since evbuffer_add_file already uses sendfile (if it finds it) this is not really an issue.

So I removed the loop completely and tried.  But the contents are still not being sent.  but atleast this time I dont have the bad file descriptor error (you are right - this was due to the file being closed - a check of file handles confirmed this!).

Comment: Sri, please update your question with this note and accept an answer (or add comments to a question), try not to add clarification in other answers